# Presense of input() function causes multiprocessing to fail. What is the reason behind this?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have a simple web scraping script that uses multiprocessing. I want the user to choose which excel file is being scraped, so `input()` is used at the beginning.

Without the multiprocessing code, the script runs fine (though it's processing links one at a time). With the multiprocessing code, the script hangs indefinitely. This is true even if I don't use the string collected from `input()` in the script, so it seems it's just the very presence of `input()` that is causing the script to hang with multiprocessing present.

I haven't got a clue why this would be the case. Any insight is really appreciated.

The code:

```py
os.chdir(os.path.curdir)

# excel_file_name_b is not used in the script at all, but because
# it exists, the script hangs. Ideally I want to keep input() in the script
excel_file_name_b = input()
excel_file_name = "URLs.xlsx"

excel_file = openpyxl.load_workbook(excel_file_name)
active_sheet = excel_file.active
rows = active_sheet.max_row

for i in range(2,rows+1,1):
    list.append(active_sheet.cell(row=i,column=1).value)

headers = {"User-Agent":'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36',"Accept-Language": 'en-GB'}

def scrape(url):
    try:
        res = get(url, headers = headers)
        html_soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'lxml')
        html_element = html_soup.select('._3pvwV0k')
        return res.url, html_element[0].getText()
    except:
        return res.url, "Not found or error"
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Pool(10)
    scrape_return = p.map(scrape, list)
    for k in range(len(scrape_return)):
        try:
            active_sheet.cell(row=k+2, column=2).value = scrape_return[k][0]
            active_sheet.cell(row=k+2, column=3).value = scrape_return[k][1]
        except:
            continue

excel_file.save(excel_file_name)
```

Comment: When you say "hangs" do you mean "stops, waiting for input"? What happens if you type stuff in when it's stopped? Waiting for input is exactly what the `input()` function does, so it's not clear what you'd expect it to do differently.

Comment: So if you comment the `excel_file_name_b = input()` line, it suddenly works?

Comment: I expect the problem is that the input is at module level. You should move it (and all the rest of the code at that level) into the `if __name__ == '__main__':` block, or preferably into a function called from there.

Comment: @tevemadar yep that's correct.

Comment: @Blckknght This is after you have typed something in. The script won't run the multiprocess block, and if you type stuff in during that part nothing happens.
@DanielRoseman I have tried this now (@GiraffeMan91 also recommended this) and it works! There is another problem however which is everything within   `if __name__ == '__main__':` gets repeated for each URL it finds the excel file. Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your `input()` is at module level, each process is calling it to have it available for the process to use.

Multiprocessing closes stdin which is what causes each of your errors. [[docs]](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html)

If you move it to `if __name__ == '__main__':` you shouldn't have the problem any more.

**Edit:** reformatting your code more similar to below will probably clear up the other issues with it not performing as expected.

```py
def scrape(url):
    headers = {"User-Agent":'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36',"Accept-Language": 'en-GB'}
    try:
        res = get(url, headers=headers)
        html_soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'lxml')
        html_element = html_soup.select('._3pvwV0k')
        return res.url, html_element[0].getText()
    except:
        return res.url, "Not found or error"
        pass


def main():
    excel_file_name_b = input()
    excel_file_name = "URLs.xlsx"
    excel_file = openpyxl.load_workbook(excel_file_name)
    active_sheet = excel_file.active
    rows = active_sheet.max_row

    for i in range(2,rows+1,1):
        list.append(active_sheet.cell(row=i,column=1).value)   # rename this object, list is a keyword



    p = Pool(10)
    scrape_return = p.map(scrape, list)   # rename here too
    for k in range(len(scrape_return)):
        try:
            active_sheet.cell(row=k+2, column=2).value = scrape_return[k][0]
            active_sheet.cell(row=k+2, column=3).value = scrape_return[k][1]
        except:
            continue

    excel_file.save(excel_file_name)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Thank you, this seems to have fixed this problem.  That said everything within `if __name__ == '__main__':` is being repeated for each URL in the excel file and I'm not completely why that's happening.

Comment: I edited to show an example of how I would reformat your code, if you take an approach more similar to that it will probably clear up some of your issues, but I can't be sure because I don't have the excel file or the rest of your code to test it out.

Comment: GiraffeMan91 Thank you very much for editing the code! I would not have guessed to organise it like that. Thanks for the help this has fixed the problem I was having.